# Select all a element in website using pure js

Tags: javascript

I want to select all the countries names in the tbody

[image]

website: https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

i tried

```
document.querySelector("#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-of-type(1n) > td:nth-of-type(1n) > a").innerText
```

it gives only the first country

i think i need to use loop to fetch lines but i don't know how

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll()` to get all matches. `querySelector()` just returns the first.

Comment: @Barmar `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 1 argument required, but only 0 present. at <anonymous>:1:10
`

Comment: You left out the argument containing the selector expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

**UPDATE**

Most country elements do not have links, so you have to just get the `td` without the `a` tag. Please check the updated code with the updated selector `#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr > td:nth-child(1)`.

To print the values:

```js
const selector = "#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr > td:nth-child(1)";

document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => console.log(el.textContent.trim()));
```

To get an array with the values:

```js
const selector = "#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr > td:nth-child(1)";

const counties = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].map(el => el.textContent.trim());
```

Comment: it doesn't give all the list, because the other countries have different seletor, without a tag

Comment: You have to change the selector and exclude the anchor tag `a`, because most countries do not have links. Please check my updated code and selector. **TIP**: You can add `.trim()` at the end of `el.textContent.trim()` to get rid of the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` returns the first matching element. You need to use `querySelectorAll` to get *all* matching elements, then you can iterate the collection based on your requirements.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 1 argument required, but only 0 present. at <anonymous>:1:10

Comment: You need to provide the css selector as an argument (the same value you used in the question)

Comment: @Amit i did `document.querySelectorAll("#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-of-type(1n) > td:nth-of-type(1n) > a").innerText`

Comment: It returns a list of elements, you need to loop over them to get all their `innerText`.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, i got `undefined`

Comment: because you need to loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Comment: I@Amit `document.querySelectorAll` will return an array, you need to iterate (loop) over those results.

Comment: @rhys_stubbs it returns a NodeList, not an array.

Comment: i'm wondering why you don't just post the answer if you already know it, i'm not a javascript dev, and trying to work with selectors just hard for me atleast for now

Comment: @VLAZ Indeed it does, the OP is clearly a new to programming so I thought I would add a simple explanation that they may better understand. For the sake of simplicity, the OP may want to use `Array.from` to convert the NodeList to a normal array

Comment: @rhys_stubbs `document.querySelectorAll("#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-of-type(1n) > td:nth-of-type(1n) > a")` give NodeList that there text contain the country name, how can extract those countries using loop ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-of-type(1n) > td:nth-of-type(1n) > a");

// iterate over the NodeList
nodeList.forEach(element => {

    // access each element here
    console.log(element.innerText);

});

// OR iterate over an array
const elementsArray = Array.from(nodeList);

elementsArray.forEach(element => {

    // access each element here
    console.log(element.innerText);

});
```

Comment: it doesn't give all the list, because the other countries have different seletor, without a tag

Comment: @user11845248 If the CSS selector that you have given does not work you need to provide a better example of the HTML.

Comment: @user11845248 My mistake, unfortunately I’m on a smart phone and unable to inspect the source.

Comment: Thanks to you and @xxMePHDxx, i got the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to use `querySelectorAll` to return a `NodeList` of elements and use selector that selects all first column from table with id `main_table_countries` as below

```
let countries = [...document.querySelectorAll('table#main_table_countries tbody:nth-child(2) tr td:nth-child(1)')].map(e=>e.innerText);
console.log(countries);
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @rhys_stubbs, i got the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Combining @xxMrPHDxx and @rhys_stubbs answers, i finally figure it out

```
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("table#main_table_countries tr td:nth-child(1)");

// iterate over the NodeList
nodeList.forEach(element => {

    // access each element here
    console.log(element.innerText);

});

// OR iterate over an array
const elementsArray = Array.from(nodeList);

elementsArray.forEach(element => {

    // access each element here
    console.log(element.innerText);

});
```

Comment: Actually you'll need the `tbody:nth-child(2)` part to avoid **Total** column in the last row